# x86_64 jumping to writable address

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to write a C program on Linux that jumps to a location that can be written by the program itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char a[] = {0x41, 0x5c, 0x41, 0x5d, 0x41, 0x5e, 0x41, 0x5f, 0x0};
    __asm__("pop %%r12;"
            "jmp *%[a];"
            "pop %%r11;" : : [a] "r" (a) : );
    return 0;
}
```

Array `a` contains instruction `pop %r12; pop %r13; pop %r14; pop %r15`, and I hope to use the jmp instruction to jump to array `a`'s address and execute the instructions.

However, this program raises segment fault when executing. I used `gcc` to compile my program and `gdb` to step through each instruction. What I find is that the program successfully jumps to array `a`'s address, but before it can execute the first instruction, the it receives signal SIGSEGV.

Why is this happening? Does it mean that I cannot jump to a writable location? Is this a hardware limitation? (If so, how can I check whether my CPU supports this kind of jump? )

I am using a x86_64 CPU, and the program is compiled in 64-bit mode.

Comment: By default the stack is mapped read+write but not execute.  You want `gcc -zexecstack`.  But I don't understand why you're popping whatever's on the stack before jumping, or including a `pop` *after* the jmp (which doesn't have any way to return).  Normally you'd just cast it to a function pointer and call it, so the C compiler emits a `call` instruction.

Comment: The pop instructions are just random instructions (may be replaced by other instructions later). I think the `-zexecstack` solves my problem.

Comment: Replaced later how?  Not at runtime, because you don't have the address of that code.  If you want to use `call` instead of `jmp` and have your machine code actually return, you should *not* use inline asm for this.  You're clobbering the compiler's registers without telling it, and you inevitably clobber the red-zone where the compiler might have been keeping stuff below RSP.  Cast to a function pointer.  See the linked duplicate for the syntax for casting to a function pointer and dereferencing the result to get a return value.

Comment: Normally, the pages of your program's memory that are writable are set as non-executable, and those that are executable are set as non-writable.  You can change protections for a region of memory by calling `mprotect(2)`.